# nopCommerce Lable display with "." Issue eg:featured.product

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

im using nopCommerce version 3.5 and powerhub theme

issue:
some of the lables(links) are not displaying the exact name instead displays with "."(dot)

in footer contact us displayed like below

```
contact.address
contact.number
contact.email
```

[here is the link](http://screencast.com/t/hJECalKEG) of the issue

please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you please give a code example from where labels are generated inside Views? These may be references to language entries that could not be resolved.

Comment: i removed address column in footer and this is the issue in powerhub theme. Powerhub theme demo link is [here](http://powerhub.nopcommerce-theme.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file Footer.cshtml in the theme.

\Themes\PowerHub\Views\Common\Footer.cshtml